# Openshift does not scale on high traffic

Tags: scale, openshift, traffic, http-status-code-503, gears

On our openshift (jboss) application are 16 gears available.
But openshit does not scale.
If 50 users are online on our application (we can track it with google analytics), we are getting the following error:

503 errors (Service Temporarily Unavailable)

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not give enough information about what does not work. Have you looked at the logs to see if you are getting error. You can use rhc tail command to look at the logs. Have you done some analysis on what is the bottleneck of your application. In OpenShift database does not scale. How many database connections are you creating? Have you tried configuring number of JBoss instance? How are you load testing the application? What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: We are using the database from AWS (RDS).
The Application was not too slow. But after ~30 minutes it is suddenly offline. (http-error: 503)

Comment: Here is the log data:

Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.

 proxy 'express' has no server available!